# sqlalchemy do aggregation for a complex join

Tags: python, sql, join, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Apologies for the bad title as I'm not sure what the exact issue is apart from my sql skills.

I have the following models (stripped down for clarity):

```
class Student (db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   good_behaviour_marks = db.Column(db.Integer)
   tests = db.relationship('Test', backref='student', lazy='dynamic', cascade='all, delete-orphan')

   @hybrid_property
   def total_marks(self):
      marks = self.good_behaviour_marks
      for test in tests:
          marks += tests.score
      return marks

class Test (db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   subject = db.Column(db.String)
   score = db.Column(db.Integer)
   student_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Student.id'))
```

A student can take tests of multiple subjects. I want to write a query to get sum of total_marks for all students that took the Math test.

Example:

```
Student1 -> id:1 good_behaviour_marks:5 tests:[Math:10, Science:20] total_marks: 50
Student2 -> id:2 good_behaviour_marks:2 tests:[Science:15, English:20] total_marks:37
Student3 -> id:3 good_behaviour_marks:4 tests:[Math:10, Spanish:10] total_marks:24
```

The query should return -> 50 + 24 = 74 which is sum of total_marks of those students who had Math as one of the subjects.

I'm using flask-sqlalchemy, if that helps. I have some idea of the structure of the sql query:

```
select sum(total_marks)
from (
   ( 
      select 
        id, total_marks
      from student
   ) a
   leftjoin
   (
      select
        student_id
      from test
      where subject=='Math'
   ) b
   on (a.id == b.student_id)
   group_by (id)
)
```

but I'm not successful in converting it to sqlalchemy query. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to perform a join between Student and Test, filter on those that have the Math test and then use the aggregation function to sum up the total marks. Like so:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

# perform the join
students_with_math_tests = db.session.query(Student).join(
    Test, Test.student_id == Student.id
).filter(
    Test.subject == 'Math'
)

# calculate total marks
total_marks_sum = sum(student.total_marks for student in students_with_math_tests)

print(total_marks_sum)
```

This is simple and might not be good for large datasets.
Alternatively, you can also handle the sum directly within the query:

```
result = db.session.query(
    func.sum(Student.good_behaviour_marks + func.coalesce(func.sum(Test.score), 0))
).join(
    Test, Test.student_id == Student.id
).filter(
    Test.subject == 'Math'
).group_by(
    Student.id
).all()

# since result will return a list of sums for each student, sum them up to get the total
total_marks_sum = sum(x[0] for x in result)

print(total_marks_sum)
```

This is a bit more complex but should be way more efficient. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is definitely one way but I'm wondering if something can be done on the lines of: db.session.query(func.sum(Student.total_marks)).join(Test, Test.student_id == Student.id).filter(Test.subject == 'Math').scalar()
This is obviously wrong but just want to know if something can be worked on these lines.